# GPG encrypt file prompt asking for password repeats infinitely

Tags: bash, encryption, gnupg

I'm using [GNUPG lib](https://gnupg.org/software/libraries.html) for encrypt/decrypt a file. I'm trying to create a bash.sh script I could call from CLI to encrypt and decrypt quickly a specific file on my computer like this:

```
# Open my encrypted file
$ mybashfile.sh

# Save and encrypt my file
$ mybashfile.sh -save
```

Here is the bash script I have wrote:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# mybashfile.sh

FOLDER="/Users/myFolder/"
FILE_ENCRYPT="file.txt.gpg"
FILE="file.txt"

# if flag -save is passed from the CLI

if  [[ $1 = "-save" ]]; then
    
    echo "Start encrypt and save file"

    # laucnh file encryption with gpg
    gpg -c ${FOLDER}${FILE}

    if test -f ${FOLDER}${FILE_ENCRYPT}; then

        # if file has been encrypted with gpg -> remove original file
        rm ${FOLDER}${FILE}
    else

        echo "error -> file cant be encrypted"
    fi

else

    echo "Start open and decrypt file"

    # launch file decryption with gpg
    gpg ${FOLDER}${FILE_ENCRYPT}

    if test -f ${FOLDER}${FILE}; then

        # if file has been decrypted -> open it
        rm ${FOLDER}${FILE_ENCRYPT}
        open ${FOLDER}${FILE}
    else

        echo "error -> file cant be decrypted"
    fi

fi
```

I have no ideas why but when calling `$ mybashfile.sh -save` (equivalent of `gpg -c /Users/myFolder/file.txt`) GPG ask me to enter a password from the CLI (which is the normal behavior) then will repeat this action for ever and ever. I can't do anything else than typing a new password, then a new again, again and again... No ways for me to confirm the previous password to complete the creation of the script...

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You're probably asked to confirm the passphrase you first entered. If you enter it twice without errors it should stop there. Suggestion: before using your script try to run these `gpg` commands manually to better understand how they work.

Comment: Since you have neither loops nor recursive calls in your script, the problem must be the `gpg` command itself. Although the logic in your program is pretty straightforward, I would for the safe side run the script with `set -x` and, from the output, copy the **ecact** pgp command, which is being generated, and try to repeat it from the command line. I would also put a `type pgp` into your script, to ensure that for repetition on the command line, you use the exactly same _pgp_ (and not an alias or shell function of the same name).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks for suggestions -> I did use GPG first from commande line to understand. I don't have any confirm prompt, only a 'enter password' prompt which repeats popin and popin whatever I enter in it...

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for helping. I can't find `set -x` commande from the documentation... Could you write a more detailed example?

Comment: @Faks And it never stops even if you always enter the same passphrase? Try with a super-simple passphrase, maybe, just to be sure it is not due to typos.

Comment: @Faks: In the bash man-page, search the section _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_ and then scroll down to the description of the `set` command. You use `set -x` to turn on logging/debugging, and you will see on stderr exactly, which command is going to be executed (i.e. after expansion).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Yes, even with a super-simple phrase, it prompts the same question again and again...

Comment: @Faks Then I have no clue, sorry. `gpg -c` works fine here with `gpg 2.2.33` under macOS 10.14.6 and also `gpg 2.2.27` under Debian 11.1. In both cases the passphrase is asked for only twice.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks for your help. Did you try with my bash script? When using GPG only from CLI I have no problem, but when using/calling my bash script (which should call GPG from CLI too) I have the infinite prompt problem...

Comment: @Faks Ah! Sorry, I misunderstood one of your previous comment and thought you had the same issue with the CLI. Yes, I tried with your bash script and it worked as expected here, again with `gpg 2.2.33` under macOS 10.14.6 and also `gpg 2.2.27` under Debian 11.1. In both cases the passphrase is asked for only twice. And decryption works too.